# Are there environment variables available to an Alexa Hosted Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have written an [Alexa hosted skill](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html), which I would like to open source as a friend would like to join me in working on it. It uses Googles [Geocoding Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview), which relies on an API key. Currently, this API key sits In my python source code:

```
...
import logging

GOOGLE_API_KEY = "KEY"
GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_PATH = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

def get_lat_lon(address):
...
```

I want to upload my source code to GitHub (preferably public), whilst still hosting the application (ultimately a lambda function) using Alexa Hosting, which is eases up a lot of the infrastructure. Is there any way to define environment variables for an Alexa hosted application, so that my private API key is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion. Store your API key on dynamoDB and fetch whenever required. You will need to write an extra piece of code that reads from dynamoDB using boto3 library and then store the key on your variable.

```
import logging

GOOGLE_API_KEY = get_apikey_db()
GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_PATH = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"


def get_apikey_db():
    #read from db here

def get_lat_lon(address):
...
```

I hope this solves your problem.